# Justification for the way s is computed in DSA?

Tags: dsa

I am sorry if this is a naive question but is there any justification for the way that `s` is computed in the DSA signature algorithm:

$$
s = k^{-1} * (rx + m)
$$

This looks to me like a very arbitrary combination of $k$, $r$, $x$ and $m$. Is this just one particular way that's found to work or does it actually have some kind of structure/reason behind it that I am missing?

Comment: I'll vote this up because the Wikipedia page doesn't show the Discrete Logarithm problem. You should however read into it a bit before asking, did you read [the paper by Divest, Shamir and Adleman](https://www.ipa.go.jp/security/enc/CRYPTREC/fy15/doc/1003_DSA.pdf)?